# When copying the _id value to other field in the same document using cursor foreach(), is not working

Tags: mongodb

When copying the _id value to other field in the same document using cursor foreach(), is giving wrong value;
Intention:
I have a messages collection which contain a Message object inside.Here i want to add a field "MessageId" in Message object with the string value of _id of the document.But when i run this query on my db,first document's MessageId holding the value of _id of second document , and second hold the value of third..like that.
Following is the query;

```
db.messages.find().forEach(
    function(message){
    db.messages.update(
        {"Message.MessageId":{$exists:false}},
        {$set:{"Message.MessageId":message._id+''}}
    )
});
```

Where i am wrong..???

Answer (score 0):

Your `update` call matches all docs without a `Message.MessageId` field, not just the one you're trying to target.  Add `_id: message._id` to the conditions parameter to only target the doc that `message` represents:

```js
db.messages.find().forEach(
    function(message){
        db.messages.update(
            {_id: message._id, "Message.MessageId":{$exists: false}},
            {$set:{
                "Message.MessageId": message._id+''     
            }}
        );
    }
);
```

But you could make this more efficient by including the `$exists` check in your `find` call instead so that you're only iterating over the docs that need to be updated:

```js
db.messages.find({"Message.MessageId":{$exists: false}}).forEach(
    function(message){
        db.messages.update(
            {_id: message._id},
            {$set:{
                "Message.MessageId": message._id+''     
            }}
        );
    }
);
```